# ASUS All-in-one model ET2410IUTS-B034C touch screen drivers Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: 12.10, asus, touchscreen

Bought an Asus all-in-one for my 90 year old mom. Won't let her run Windows for security reasons, but would like her to be able to use touch screen. Need a how-to for the ASUS ET2410 if it is possible. I don't know what the touch screen hardware is on this unit. Tried the latest (0.6.5.0) nwfermi driver but got "Dependency is not satisfiable:xf86-input-newxtwindow".

Comment: Edit: lsusb reports:Bus 002 Device 003: ID 1926:0dbf NextWindow

Answer (score 1):

you can dowload a deb from the following link https://launchpad.net/~djpnewton/+archive/xf86-input-nextwindow

Comment: Could you explain, by editing your answer, to the person who has asked the question, what this would do and how it may help them.